# Pushing only the last commit in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, version-control, push

After making several local commits in VS2013, is there a way to only push the last one and discard the rest? I like to commit after making small changes but would like to push to remote server only after finishing everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Squashing in VS2013

If I understand you correctly, you would like to `squash` your last N commits into 1 commit before pushing. This can be a good practice if you've committed a lot during debug/devel and would like to have a feature contained in a single commit message.

According to [this reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286572.aspx) you won't be able to do it from within Visual Studio.

#### Squashing in Git Bash

If you do it from within a command-line client like Git Bash, you can use interactive rebase.

Example: if you want to squash your last 4 commits in 1 commit:

```
git checkout feature-branch
git rebase -i HEAD~4
```

This means, rebase your current tip to HEAD~4 with `interactive` rebase. This opens an editor listing the 4 commits (in the order in which they were written). The action do be done for each commit is `pick` by default, because that's what rebase does. Leave `pick` on the first one, but replace `pick` with `s` (or `squash`) for the last 3. That means each of those commits will be combined with the previous one.

From there you will get a second editor asking to write a single commit message for the 4 commits.

Once you close the second editor the rebase should finish by itself.

Comment: Just for reference, VS 2015.3 doesn't support this either. The (easy) manual steps are described here: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/tutorial/rebase#squash-local-commits